# Scan any twitter account

Tags: php, ajax, twitter

One of my friend give me this challenge.

> Monitor/Scan any twitter account for specified keywords inputted into the 
>       program and grab the twitter Link Instantly and proceed to add to cart. 
>       Must be using the Twitter API with oauth! Must find the tweet instantly or 
>       BEFORE it is even tweeted out by the twitter account!

Please guide me
Thanks

Comment: SO is for people with programming problems, not people with problems deciphering problems. Please at least attempt to solve the issue yourself, then come back with specific issues / questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get information based on tweets with the `twitter GET search/tweets API.`

There is no way anyone can guide you through all of this from here. But we can shoot you in the right directions and help you through the parts you get stuck at!

Here is a link to the `GET search/tweets API`

[Click Here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets)

Get the API and build a working environment on your local machine. From there if you run in to problems ask and you shall receive answers!

Hope this helps!